# Pandas list in string format to list of dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column named coor which is having dict with in a list as a string.

```
df['coor'][0]

'[{'x': 720.65215, 'y': 636.51048, 'width': 332.19348, 'height': 648.12561}, {'x': 2044.77989, 'y': 847.90622, 'width': 329.87049, 'height': 576.11169}]'
```

I tried few items like json loading, string to list conversion. no result.
Output

```
[
{'x': 720.65215, 'y': 636.51048, 'width': 332.19348, 'height': 648.12561},
{'x': 2044.77989, 'y': 847.90622, 'width': 329.87049, 'height': 576.11169}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working `ast.literal_eval` in this sample data:

```
import ast

#changed not valid `''` to `""` around string
a = "[{'x': 720.65215, 'y': 636.51048, 'width': 332.19348, 'height': 648.12561}, {'x': 2044.77989, 'y': 847.90622, 'width': 329.87049, 'height': 576.11169}]"

print (ast.literal_eval(a))
[{'x': 720.65215, 'y': 636.51048, 'width': 332.19348, 'height': 648.12561},
 {'x': 2044.77989, 'y': 847.90622, 'width': 329.87049, 'height': 576.11169}]
```